# Getting error when importing Pupperteer when running from Node server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node js application with some javascript code to import Puperteer to scrape a website. However, the following line:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
```

results in the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "fs/promises". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

If i comment out this import then i don't get this error, but obviously it's needed in order to use pupeteer. Why am i getting this error ? AFAIK i shouldn't need to import anything else if i want to use puppeteer (i have it installed) ?